# trying to change the value of attribute of one class from another class but one value changes other value remains the same

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, oop, instance

All I want to do is make the value of 'a' from second class negative each time change function is called from First class. **I don't want to directly access the 'a' variable through the instance of second class. I want to change the value of 'a' only through a different class.**

```
class First():
    def __init__(self):
        self.value = 1
        self.s = Second(self)

    def change(self):
        trigger = input("continue? y/n?")
        self.value *= -1
        print(self.value)
        print(self.s.a)
        if trigger == "y":
            self.change()

class Second():
    def __init__(self, num):
        self.a = num.value

f = First()
f.change()
```

Comment: Can you clarify your problem, or what you are trying to do? You can just assign to ``self.s.a``. What do you mean by "I want to change the value of 'a' only through a different class."? There is no "different class" in your example.

Comment: `self.a = num.value` was a *one-time event*.  You retrieved the value of `num.value`, as of that particular moment in time, and assigned it to `self.a`.  You did NOT set up any sort of ongoing process that will keep the two values in sync.  If you really can't just assign to `self.s.a`, you need for `Second` to retain a reference to `num` itself, and have `a` be a property that retrieves `num.value` every time it is referenced.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi this is not my actual code. my actual code is really big and complex and i  thought it will be too long to post here so i just simplified the part which wasn't working and put it up in this way so it will be easier for people to go through it and explain me what is wrong with it.

Comment: @jasonharper can u please show me how to do it programatically. a snippet a code will be really helpfull

Comment: I understand that this is simplified code (which is good) but it fails to demonstrate what you want to do (which is not good). Please [edit] your question describe more clearly what you want to do, possibly with *short* code to demonstrate which behaviour you desire.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi i Just want to change the value of  attribute 'a' from class Second whenever change method from class One is called. But i don't want to directly change the value of attribute 'a' from class Second by accessing the instance of Class second. whereas i want to change the value of an attribute 'value' from Class One. which intern should change the value of 'a' from class Second and the two print statements in the change method are just there to print the values of both the attribute for debugging purposs

Comment: I would start by reading https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html, which will help you understand the difference between an object and a reference to an object, and why changing the value of `f.value` doesn't change the value of `f.s.a`.

Comment: @cybertron15 The important thing is that when you say things like "which intern should change the value of 'a' from class Second", that means ``Second`` actually has an attribute that is changed to a fixed value. That rules out, for example, that ``Second`` has no changeable attribute ``a`` but merely a property that *reads* the value of ``First``'s ``value`` to compute the value of ``Second``'s ``a``. Your description currently details *how* things should happen, but not actually *what must* happen versus what is just your guess at how this could be done.

Comment: @chepner thank you for the link it was really helpful

Comment: @MisterMiyagi thanks for the suggestion i'm kinda beginner at coding and English isn't my first language so I might have messed up a little while explaining my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Make the Second class's `a` attribute a property that relies on a module level variable that the First class can change without *going through* the Second class.

```
class Thing:
    def __init__(self,val):
        self.val = val

class First():
    def __init__(self):
        self.value = 1
        self.s = Second()

    def change(self):
        trigger = input("continue? y/n?")
        self.value *= -1
        #print(self.value)
        #print(self.s.a)
        if trigger == "y":
            #self.change()
            num.val = -num.val

class Second():
    def __init__(self):
        #self.a = num.value
        pass
    @property
    def a(self):
        return num.val
    @a.setter
    def a(self,val):
        num.val = val

num = Thing(2)
f = First()
print(f'f.s.a = {f.s.a}')
f.change()
print(f'f.s.a = {f.s.a}')
```

That solution would *make* all `Second` instances have the same `num`, therfore the same `a`.

Maybe you meant for each `Second` instance to have its own unique `a`.

```
class Thing:
    def __init__(self,val):
        self.val = val

d = {}

class First():
    def __init__(self):
        self.value = 1
        self.s = Second(2)

    def change(self):
        trigger = input("continue? y/n?")
        self.value *= -1
        #print(self.value)
        #print(self.s.a)
        if trigger == "y":
            #self.change()
            d[self.s].val = d[self.s].val * -1

class Second():
    def __init__(self,val):
        num = Thing(val)
        d[self] = num
    @property
    def a(self):
        return d[self].val
    @a.setter
    def a(self,val):
        d[self].val = val

f = First()
print(f'f.s.a = {f.s.a}')
f.change()
print(f'f.s.a = {f.s.a}')
```

Comment: Why add the extra ``d``? Why not use ``self.num.val`` instead of ``d[self].val``?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi In the second solution, the dictionary will (should?) hold a separate instance of Thing for each instance of Second so that each Second instance can have a distinct `a` - unlike the first solution in my answer.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi - I'm not confident either meets the OP's requirements - we'll see.

Comment: But each ``Second`` can already have a distinct instance of ``Thing`` via an attribute, such as ``self._num = hing(val)``. What is the benefit of using *one global, external* dictionary to hold state that *each instance's internal* dictionary could hold as well?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi ... Ahh well IIUC the OP wants to change the `a` attribute in `Second` instances without accessing the attribute *through* the instance - so I figured the First instance need to manipulate a module level variable/thing the the Second instance *relies on* for its attribute - hope that made as much sense as the question.

Comment: @wwii i  appreciate your answer but i really did not understand how it worked as i'm not that advanced programmer

Comment: @MisterMiyagi - I guess I might not understand what you are asking. I used a dictionary to store different instances of Things, one for each instance of Second.  I couldn't see any other way to affect a Second's  `a` attribute indirectly and have multiple independent Seconds and `a`'s.

Comment: @wwii You can directly store *anything* on each Second instance, including the respective Thing instance. Forego the ``d`` mapping and store ``num`` directly on ``self`` as an attribute, instead of ``d[self]``: Inside ``__init__``, store ``self._num = num``; the getter is then ``return self._num.val``, and the setter is ``self._num.val = val``.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi - That is true but the OP wants to affect the `a` attribute of a Second instance **without** *doing* `second_instance.a = val` so First instances need a way to get access to each Thing - that is why I chose to put the Things in a dictionary. I may have completely misunderstood OP's intent and/or this may not be a good solution but it is what I thought of. I certainly don't mind down votes - I think having bad answers on the site can also be  instructive if their badness is identified for readers.

Comment: I did not downvote. I can't say whether it is per-se wrong or not – I *literally* have no idea why one would do it this way.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi maybe write an answer the way you are suggesting to give some contrast or feel free to edit mine adding the other way to do it.

Comment: I'm not comfortable with writing or editing an answer to a question I do not understand.